# Can't get LazyLoad and onerror to work together on an image

Tags: html, image, onerror, jquery-lazyload

I have some images on my page:

```
<img src="http://www.abc/images/abc.jpg" />
```

If the image can't be loaded (because `abc.jpg` doesn't exist, for example), then I show a "default" image instead:

```
<img src="http://www.abc/images/abc.jpg" onerror="this.src='http://www.abc/images/default.jpg'" />
```

If I add [LazyLoad](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload) to my image and load an even more lightweight default image, it becomes:

```
<img
    class="lazy"
    data-original="http://www.abc/images/abc.jpg"  
    src="http://www.abc/images/graydefault.jpg"
    onerror="this.src='http://www.abc/images/default.jpg'" />
```

Now, when the page loads, it will first load the lightweight image, before loading the actual image.

But what happens if the actual image doesn't exist? The lightweight default image will stay there, but that's not what I want:

**How can I load my default image (`default.jpg`) on error?**

PS: Default image is quite heavy, so I would like to avoid loading it as the default image.

Comment: that should be `<img src=...`

Comment: @MinNaingOo didnt understand u ?

Comment: that should be `<img src=...` . not `<img scr=...`

Comment: Try lazy load xt http://plugins.jquery.com/lazyloadxt/, it supports optional error handler.

Comment: @MinNaingOo thanks buddy , but it was typing error , in code i user SRC :)

Answer (score 1):

Use "appear" option in lazyload js. Use the following code in lazy load js for on-error image src loading

```
appear: function(ele,settings)
{
    $(ele).attr("src",$(ele).attr("data-original"));
}
```

This function replaced src by data-original when image is avaible in view port. if data-original image url is not loaded, on-error image is loaded.